# Excel VBA: Indexing a collection of SpecialCells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've noticed that if you apply the SpecialCells method to a range, and then index the elements of the resulting collection, what is returned are all the elements of the original range, not of the new range based on the SpecialCells criteria.

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Range

    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Select

    For Each i In Selection
        Debug.Print i
    Next

End Sub
```

For example, if you run the above code based on a range consisting of a constant, followed by a formula, followed by a constant, and then check the elements of Selection in the Immediate window you get the values: 1, 2, 3 (see image below).

However, if you iterate through the Selection, the values 1 and 3 are returned, as expected (again, see image below). Does anyone know why the returned values differ in each case?

[image]

Comment: Selection is an Application object property. It's not a Range object, it has a special type that resembles the Variant type. When iterate over Selection using ForEach, it iterates like Selection-Area-Cell. View Selection.Address and Selection.Areas(i).Address. When you use Selection(params), Selection is converted to Range, and it is treated as Range(Selection.Address)(params). If Selection contains a list of areas, the address of the first area is used. Params in this case is offset, so both Selection(X) and Selection(X,Y) is valid. And the values of X,Y formally oversized do not cause error.

Comment: This line needs modification,, replace `.Select` with `.Activate` `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Activate`. Each Selection makes selection object & Activate simply makes the object the active object. Best way to understand this is **"many cells can be selected, but only one may be the active cell at any given time."** With Active I've tried  3 situations. First is  1,2,3 other is 1,=2,3 & last one is 1, A1+A2=2 , 3 and the code returns 1, 2 & 3 in every situation.

Comment: I'm posting another VBA code, uses Range to use and its also produces 1, 2 & 3 in all 3 situations, what I've described in previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Situations to Test Collection in B1:B3 :**

1. `1,2,3`.
2. `1 =2, 3`.
3. `1, =a1+a2, 3`.

   ```
   Sub TestofCollection()
     Dim Collection1 As Collection
      Dim n As Integer
       Dim x As Integer

      Set Collection1 = New Collection

      n = 1

     On Error Resume Next
        For Each Cell In Range("B1:B3")
           Collection1.Add n, CStr(Cell.Value)
           n = n + 1
       Next Cell
    On Error GoTo 0

    For x = 1 To Collection1.Count
       Range("C" & x).Value = Collection1.Item(x)
    Next x

   End Sub
   ```